# Dot net, Some Views can't access css&js files

Tags: javascript, html, css, .net, asp.net-mvc

The problem here is that some views (not all of them) can't access to some css&js files(not all of them) ("404 Not found" error).
For exemple View of .../Details/Index/1 can't access to 1file css and 1file js (it can access all other files), but the View of .../Recherche/result can access to all files.
This problem happens when the user is connected and when not connected.
I didn't modifie the web.config file.
All View are related to one Layout, in there I inluded the css files:

```
<link href="Content/file.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And one last thing, all css files are in 1 folder and all js files are in 1 folder.

Comment: What's your code for including the CSS and JavaScript files?

Comment: You need to use absolute URLs.

Comment: updated ! (I don't know what do you mean by saying "check the console")

Comment: Open your browser's dev tools and look at the errors.

Comment: You mean with no /{id} at the end? and why is that?

Comment: Fire bug :"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:4567/Details/Index/file.min.js"

Comment: Can you tell me why I need to use only absolute URLs? because I need the /{id} in the URL in order to not use Post methodes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute vs relative URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: Use `<link href="~/Content/file.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the path to the file with the tilde (`~`) character. Razor will converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.

```
<link href="~/Content/file.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If you are using an MVC version prior to MVC 4, you should use [Url.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) helper method.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/file.css")"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Correct! Also i strongly advice to use bundling feature of MVC. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification